# Why C# compiler use an invalid method's overload?

Tags: c#, oop

I have been confused by the following code

```
class A
{
    public void Abc(int q)
    {
        Console.Write("A");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public void Abc(double p)
    {
        Console.Write("B");
    }
}

    ...
    var b = new B();
    b.Abc((int)1);
```

The result of code execution is "B" written to console.

In fact the B class contains two overloads of Abc method, the first for int parameter, the second one for double. Why the compiler use a double version for an integer argument?

Be careful the method abc(double) doesn't shadow or override the method abc(int)

Comment: i suspect you have to say `A b = new B()`

Comment: yup. you have to tell it that it is of type `A` because the `B` implementation shadows `A`'s implementation

Comment: @DarrenKopp - No, it doesn't shadow. It's an overload, and that's perfectly fine.

Comment: @JoshuaShearer - No, it's not a duplicate. This is overloading, not shadowing and not overriding.

Comment: No shadowing and now overriding, just a compile time binding.

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh It's not an invalid overload resolution. It's valid. It's according to the spec.

Comment: Consider if you'd written B and that call to `b.Abc()` and then the author of A came along and added it's `Abc()`. They'd have just broken your call by making it call a different method, but they couldn't know that they would. In the other direction, if the author of `Abc()` didn't want this to happen, then they should have picked a different name.

Comment: The method chosen is not invalid; it is an applicable method. Imagine you removed the base class method; would you expect the derived class method to still be chosen?

Comment: Consider also this scenario: there is only the derived class method. The developer of the code doing the call tests the code and it works great, calling the derived class method.  Now the author of the base class adds a method to the base class **and the calling code now suddenly starts calling a completely different method, in an untested scenario, where the callee is a less specific class**.  If you've tested a method call and determined that it works with derived class SwissBankAccount, you don't want the author of the BankAccount class to be able to change that binding!

Comment: @EricLippert For this case the compiler will show a warning about method shadowing

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Since the compiler can implicitly convert the int to double, it chooses the B.Abc method. This is explained in [this post by Jon Skeet](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Overloading) (search for "implicit"):

> The target of the method call is an expression of type Child, so the
> compiler first looks at the Child class. There's only one method
> there, and it's applicable (there's an implicit conversion from int to
> double) so that's the one that gets picked. The compiler doesn't
> consider the Parent method at all.
>
> The reason for this is to reduce the risk of the brittle base class
> problem...

[More from Eric Lippert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/future-breaking-changes-part-three)

> As the standard says, “methods in a base class are not candidates if any method in a derived class is applicable”.

> In other words, the overload resolution algorithm starts by searching
> the class for an applicable method. If it finds one then all the other
> applicable methods in deeper base classes are removed from the
> candidate set for overload resolution. Since Delta.Frob(float) is
> applicable, Charlie.Frob(int) is never even considered as a candidate.
> Only if no applicable candidates are found in the most derived type do
> we start looking at its base class.

Things get a little more interesting if we extend the example in your question with this additional class that descends from A:

```
class C : A {
    public void Abc(byte b) {
        Console.Write("C");
    }
}
```

If we execute the following code

```
int i = 1;
b.Abc((int)1);
b.Abc(i);
c.Abc((int)1);
c.Abc(i);
```

the results are `BBCA`. This is because in the case of the B class, the compiler knows it can implicitly cast **any** int to double. In the case of the C class, the compiler knows it can cast the literal int 1 to a byte (because the value 1 fits in a byte) so C's Abc method gets used. The compiler, however, can't implicitly cast any old int to a byte, so `c.Abc(i)` can't use C's Abc method. It must use the parent class in that case.

[This page on Implicit Numeric Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions) shows a compact table of which numeric types have implicit conversions to other numeric types.

Answer (score 12):

You get the same functionality even when you define `B` as:

```
class B : A
{
    public void Abc(object p)
    {
        Console.Write("B");
    }
}
```

Simply, it's because overload resolution is done by looking at methods defined in the *current class*. If there are any suitable methods in the current class, it stops looking. Only if there are no suitable matches does it look at base classes

You can take a look at the [Overload resolution spec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336(v=vs.71).aspx) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks for a link to C# speck, it is not easy to remember all details!

Answer (score 7):

Different languages (such as C++, Java, or C#) have vastly different overload resolution rules.  In C#, the overload was correctly chosen as per the language spec.  If you wanted the other overload to be chosen, you have a choice.  Remember this:

> When a derived class intends to declare another overload for an inherited method, so as to treat all available overloads as equal-rights peers, it must also explicitly override all the inherited overloads with a base call as well.

What is the language design benefit of requiring this exercise?

Imagine that you are using a 3rd party library (say, .NET framework) and deriving from one of its classes.  At some point you introduce a private method called `Abc` (a new, unique name, not an overload of anything).  Two years later you upgrade the 3rd party library version without noticing that they also added a method, accessible to you and called, regrettably, `Abc`, except that it has a different parameter type somewhere (so the upgrade doesn't alert you with a compile time error) and it behaves subtly differently or maybe even has a different purpose altogether.  Do you really want one half of your private calls to `Abc` to be silently redirected to the 3rd party `Abc`?  In Java, this may happen.  In C# or C++, this isn't going to happen.

The upside of the C# way is that it's somewhat easier, for a redistributed library, to add functionality while rigorously keeping backward compatibility.  In two ways actually:

- You won't ever mess with your customers' private method calls inside their own code.
- You won't ever break your customers by adding a new uniquely named method, although you must still think twice before adding an overload of YOUR own existing method.

The downside of the C# way is that it cuts a hole into the OOP philosophy of overriding methods ever changing only the implementation, but not the API of a class.